# How to close dropdown when click anywhere in vue js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to ask how do i close the dropdown that opens when i click anywhere?

This is the code that i made.

```html
<template>
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item" @click="activeLink">
                <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: isActive}" :to="{name: 'Article'}">
                    <i class="nav-icon fa fa-upload"></i> Article
                </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown" disabled>
                <div class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" @click="HandleClick"><i class="nav-icon icon-credit-card"></i> Transaction</div>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                    <li class="nav-item" @click="activeLink">
                        <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: isActive}" :to="{name: 'Buy'}">
                            <i class="nav-icon icon-list"></i> Buy
                        </router-link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown" disabled>
                <div class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" @click="HandleClick"><i class="nav-icon fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Users</div>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                  <li class="nav-item" @click="activeLink">
                    <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: isActive}" :to="{name: 'All'}">
                      <i class="nav-icon icon-list"></i> All
                    </router-link>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" @click="activeLink">
                    <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: isActive}" :to="{name: 'Roles'}">
                      <i class="nav-icon icon-list"></i> Roles
                    </router-link>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" @click="activeLink">
                    <router-link class="nav-link" :class="{active: isActive}" :to="{name: 'Permissions'}">
                      <i class="nav-icon icon-list"></i> Permissions
                    </router-link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
```

And is my js.

```js
<script>
import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway'
import { hideMobile } from '@coreui/vue/src/mixins/hideMobile'
import { togglePs } from '@coreui/vue/src/mixins/togglePs'
export default {
  name: 'DefaultContainer',
  mixins: [ clickaway, hideMobile , togglePs],
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    name () {
      return this.$route.name
    },
    list () {
      return this.$route.matched.filter((route) => route.name || route.meta.label )
    },
    psSettings: () => {
      // ToDo: find better rtl fix
      return {
        maxScrollbarLength: 200,
        minScrollbarLength: 40,
        suppressScrollX: getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('html')).direction !== 'rtl',
        wheelPropagation: false,
        interceptRailY: styles => ({ ...styles, height: 0 })
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    scrollHandle (evt) {
      // console.log(evt)
    },
    HandleClick(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open')
    },
    activeLink(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('router-link-exact-active open')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

> And the function to open my dropdown is in HandleClick (e){} function

Do i have to differentiate each HandleClick in each dropdown so that when i click anywhere the dropdown that opens will be closed?

Or is there a better way ?

Thank You.

Comment: usually one attaches a document-wide click handler and closes the (custom) dropdown if clicked anywhere else on the document (optionally fiorwarding the document click to other handlers as well). Your module can attach only one document-wide click handler by a smart manipulation of global state and handle for all dropdowns on your vue page

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51887359/283366) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51887412/283366) regarding adding event listeners at the `document` level

Comment: @NikosM. Sorry i stil don't quite understand your answer. Do you mean i have to make every handleClick function on every dropdown?

Comment: @Phil Do you mean i have to make a function to close the dropdown then in **mounted()** i added `addEventListerner('click', this.functionRemove)` and in **beforeDestroy()** i added `removeEventListener('click', this.functionRemove)`

Comment: Yep, something like that. You'll want that function to do whatever is required to close the dropdowns

Comment: @Phil I use this for remove the **open** class `document.getElementsByClassName("nav-dropdown").classList.remove("open")` but still don't work.

Comment: for dropdown you can use vue multiselect . This component has the feature you want

Comment: @tuhin47 okay I will try it, thanks.